# How to create files with different names in a for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop

I just started learning c recently, and I haven't been able to figure this out. I'm trying to set up a for loop that will create multiple .txt files with names that differ by a number. I.E. for the first loop filename1.txt is created, for the second loop filename2.txt is created, and so on.

Comment: Use `sprintf` to generate the names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is using `sprintf`, the standard way to create a string formatted with numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void loop_through_filenames(num_files)
{
  // memory buffer for the filename.
  char filename[32];

  // File Pointer.
  FILE * fp;

  int i;
  for(i=0; i<num_files; i++){
    // Place filename in the buffer.
    sprintf(filename, "Flaming_Dragon_%d.txt", i);

    // Open the file
    fp = fopen(filename, 'w');

    // Do something if you want.

    // Close the file.
    fclose(fp);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just generate the names with `sprintf`.  Something like:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        const char *base = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "filename";
        int limit = argc > 2 ? strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10) : 10;
        const char *suffix = argc > 3 ? argv[3] : "txt";


        for( int i = 0; i < limit; i++ ){
                char path[PATH_MAX];
                snprintf(path, PATH_MAX, "%s%d%s%s", base, i,
                        *suffix ? "." : "", suffix);
                FILE * fp = fopen(path, "w");  /* Caution: will truncate extant files */
                if( fp == NULL ){
                        perror(path);
                        continue;
                }
                /* ... */
                if( fclose(fp) ){
                        perror(path);
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: What would the command line arguments look like such that `*suffix` is evaluated as False? ie. How do you pass a Null pointer through command line args?

Comment: @CSStudent7782 It can't be NULL (if it were NULL, then `*suffix` would lead to a run-time error (sigsegv)), but it can be blank.  eg `./a.out filename 10 ""`

Comment: Oh I see, then if you want the suffix to be literally `""` you need to use `./a.out filename 10 "\"\""`?

Comment: @CSStudent7782 Or `./a.out filename 10 '""'`.  There are many ways to construct strings with embedded quotes.